# Create Web Service in Ab initio

Tags: ab-initio

I have a requirement to **create a web service in AB INITIO**. Using **Java API** I need to **call** that AB INITIO web service. Pls advice, how can I create a sample web service in ABI INITIO.
I would like to know whether creating a **Web Service in AB INITIO is possible or not** ?
Provide details regarding this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create a webservice using Ab Initio.  Web Services of many sorts can be created using a continuous graph.

Read the help files, you'll be good.